# Template render callback

Tags: meteor

I'm using Handlebar's {{#each}} to render out my collection to the DOM. After each item is rendered, I want to run a script on these elements. I'm trying to find a callabck function wich fires only once, when the whole render is completed. Meteor's Template.rendered() run's each time a new item is inserted, so it runs as many times as much item I have in my collection. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`Template.foo.rendered` on the outer template (that contains the `{{#each}}`) is what you are looking for.

The thing to be aware of is that this will only run when the `{{#each}}` first renders, but you can't necessarily rely on it to re-run when (for example) more items are added to the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Use Template.created() instead of rendered(). As you've seen, rendered() will run every time the template is rendered and RE-rendered.